# Remove strange characters from cookie (VB)

Tags: c#, vb.net, cookies

I have a label (Label1.Text) that has a history of all calculator entries in my program.  I found a way to retrieve the cookie but it contains the following strange characters.  How do I remove them?

%0d%0a5+5=10

```
 Sub Page_Load(s As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If Request.Cookies("Cookie") IsNot Nothing Then
            Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies("Cookie").Value)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
Label1.Text = Uri.UnescapeDataString(Request.Cookies("Cookie").Value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Worked great!